# Angularjs: Dynamic add and remove of directives in a loop

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Having trouble with getting the code to work. Check the [codepen](http://codepen.io/nebben/pen/ZbVOKY?editors=101).

The directive `wrapper` will create a bunch of `task` directive based on the limits (`min`, `max`) provided. The information (binding) is passed from `wrapper` to `task` directive using the elements of the array `arr` in `wrapper`. Also on removal of button, its `scope` along with the associated HTML element is removed and its associated array element in `wrapper` is removed.

Try removing the buttons in the order (4,3,2,1,0) it works, but try removing the button 3 and then 4, removing of button 3 works but for 4 it crashes at `scope.twb.remove = true;` in `remove` function of `task` directive.

Probable reason for crash is on removal of button 3 its associated element in the array (at index 3. Index [0-4] for buttons [0-4]) is removed. And still the button 4 is pointing to the array element at 4th index which is missing.

How to fix the issue, or is there any other better way of going for the solution ?

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Test</title>

  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm">
  <ion-content padding="true">
    <wrapper twb="vm.twb"></wrapper>
  </ion-content>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).
controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.twb = {
      max: 5,
      min: 1,
    };
  }])
  .directive('wrapper', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="wrapper"></div>',
      replace: true,
      /* Creating an isolated scope */
      scope: {
        twb: '=',
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var base = {
          id: null,
          remove: false,
          /* function exposed by wrapper directive */
          update: update,
          /* function to be exposed by the task directive */
          destroy: null,
        };

        function update() {
          for (var i = 0; i < scope.arr.length; i++) {
            if (scope.arr[i].remove) {
              /* removing the task */
              scope.arr[i].destroy();
              /* removing the task deatils from the arr */
              scope.arr.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
        }

        scope.arr = Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.twb.max; i++) {
          scope.arr[i] = {};
          scope.arr[i] = angular.copy(base);
          scope.arr[i].id = i;
          var aTask = angular.element('<task>').attr('twb', 'arr[' + i + ']');
          element.append($compile(aTask)(scope));
        }
      }
    }
  }]).directive('task', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="task"><button ng-click="remove()" class="button button-large"> Remove ({{taskid}}) </button></div>',
      replace: true,
      /* Creating an isolated scope */
      scope: {
        twb: '=',
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.taskid = scope.twb.id;
        scope.remove = function() {
          scope.twb.remove = true;
          scope.twb.update();
        };
        scope.twb.destroy = function() {
          scope.$destroy();
          element.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your update function. It loops over an array and inside the loop an element is removed. The effect of removing (scope.arr.slice(i,1)) is of course that the element on index i is removed but additionally all elements with index greater than i will get an index = index-1. Hence your loop misses one element, the one at i+1.

To fix it, you can i-- after the splice instruction.